# What is Genome Folding?

Tags: genomes, protein-folding, human-genome

Why does [genome folding](https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=PMC3102647_2046-1682-4-8-1&req=4) have such great interest?

For protein folding I could say that's important because protein's functionality closely depends on its folded state, since it affects its mechanical properties etc.

But genome? What does it even mean to be folded? Where does it happen? Any reference to papers would be appreciated.

Comment: probably supercoiling see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK6243/. supercoiling is important to regulate transcription. Offcourse protein folding is important but to produce protein we need RNA and to produce RNA we need transcription. By tightly wouding DNA around proteins "we" can prevent RNA polymerase from transcribing the DNA and thereby silencing genes

Comment: They are not talking about supercoiling, at least solely. You said that protein function depends on its 3D structure. Well, the function of DNA  often depends on its spatial organization as well. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4792841/